# Generating a segwit (bc1) address from a brain wallet?

Tags: brain-wallet, segregated-witness

Are there any brain wallet generators that can generate segwit (bc1) addresses yet?

Comment: You can do it with the bitcoinjs library. https://github.com/bitcoinjs/bitcoinjs-lib/blob/master/README.md

Comment: But is there an example code of how to generate this address using bech?

Comment: isnt brain wallet unsafe to use? https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/8449/how-safe-is-a-brain-wallet

Comment: renlord, not all brain wallets are created equal.... warp wallets are more secure than traditional brain wallets.

Comment: A Brainwallet with sufficient entropy, generated by a computer or other device with real randomness (**not** by a human) can be secure. However, they're still a terrible trade-off between risk of theft and risk of loss. Memory can be much more flaky than people believe it to be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Memory Paper Wallet* has the ability to generate bc1 addresses from a brain wallet phrase.

https://www.xcubicle.com/memory-paper-wallet-bitcoin-ethereum-monero-ardor-litecoin

Answer (score 1):

Here's an example with bitcoinjs-lib:

```
let bitcoin = require('bitcoinjs-lib');
let assert = require('assert')
let bigi = require('bigi')


let NETWORK = bitcoin.networks.bitcoin;
let brainwallet = "This is my brain wallet and it is less secure than a CSPRNG source";
let hash = bitcoin.crypto.sha256(brainwallet);
let d = bigi.fromBuffer(hash);
let nkeyp = new bitcoin.ECPair(d);
let wif = nkeyp.toWIF();
let pubKey = nkeyp.getPublicKeyBuffer();
let scriptPubKey = bitcoin.script.witnessPubKeyHash.output.encode(bitcoin.crypto.hash160(pubKey))
let address = bitcoin.address.fromOutputScript(scriptPubKey);
console.log(address);
console.log(wif);
```

Comment: i need to try it.

Answer (score 0):

You can create one here at

```
https://segwitaddress.org/
```

You can download offline file for more security.

```
https://github.com/coinables/segwitaddress/releases
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try brain2bip.com

Checkmark "Advanced wallet recovery," then select the BIP84 tab to see a list of segwit addresses and their private keys.