# Extract private keys from litecoin-qt wallet.dat file

Tags: litecoin, electrum, wallet.dat, litecoin-qt, private-key-export

I used litecoin-qt back in 2014, and used the backup feature, which gave me a wallet.dat file... Now i want to extract the private key from the wallet.dat file so it can be used in electrum. I do not have a litecoin-qt installation. It seams like a very bad idea anyway to keep cryptocoin backups in a fileformat that depend on particular wallets etc...

Comment: Since Litecoin-Qt is essentially the same as Bitcoin Core, this question is closely related to [How can I transfer a Bitcoin-qt wallet to Electrum?](http://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/12763/5406). AFAIU, you will probably have to install Litecoin to extract the keys.