# Electrum wallet.dat

Tags: electrum, wallet-recovery

I have an old Electrum `wallet.dat` that is password protected.

I know the password, but the seed is lost.

Can this be recovered?

When trying to open the wallet in Electrum, there is an error:

[image: Error message: Cannot load wallet (1), WalletFileException('Cannot read wallet file. (parsing failed)')]

Comment: `wallet.dat` is not an Electrum wallet, it is a Bitcoin Core wallet.

Answer (score 1):

According to https://electrum.readthedocs.io/en/latest/faq.html

> The default wallet file is called default_wallet, which is created when you first run the application and is located in the /wallets folder, inside the datadir.

So, as Claris commented, `wallet.dat` is a name used by Bitcoin-core and you can't expect Electrum to read a file created by different software for its own purposes.

See [How can I transfer a Bitcoin-qt wallet to Electrum?](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/12763/13866) but take care to understand the implications of importing private keys into a HD wallet which has a recovery phrase. There is a danger that any future recovery process will lose your money.

---

You could instead download bitcoin core, run it and stop it, then replace its wallet.dat with a copy of your old wallet.dat then rrestart bitcoin core to see if it loads that file.

Comment: Ok, i never realised about core. So is electrum redundant, i can just open the wallet.dat another way? The wallet was created in electrum about 6 or 7 years ago.

Comment: @Derple: Could you have experimented with Bitcoin core 6 or 7 years ago and then decided to use Electrum instead? As far as I know, Electrum never creates a file named wallet.dat. Also see updates answer.

Comment: There is nothing redundant about Electrum, it's just a separate project, unrelated to Bitcoin Core. Bitcoin Core uses `wallet.dat` files; Electrum does not.

Comment: Electrum wallets used to be named wallet.dat