# Is it possible to import a `wallet.dat` in Electrum?

Tags: bitcoin-core, wallet, electrum, wallet-recovery, wallet.dat

I ran into an error when trying to import a `wallet.dat` into Electrum. I run Kali Linux.

[Here](https://blogger.googleusercontent.com/img/b/R29vZ2xl/AVvXsEjtuWG1mZLlEMWI_xBHEEBIglbBis7yqitNNm5kBsLgXrSHctq-d5tSjYDMkFK_Nmy7xt5ie8Qtb0oph_8gUKxMSLd3YgQfQDXgjsrQgU4vNc6dsRmACN6G3j5PMJzHBjNXdi5o8NZXjRxJOzSfqk5-hRzof7wWWAgSrOQ9u4ICPmAoNKC9r2ObdxVNibxh/s599/electrm.png) is a screenshot of the error i get.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Electrum wallat.dat](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/110610/electrum-wallat-dat)

Answer (score 2):

A `wallet.dat` file is most likely a wallet database created by the Bitcoin Core wallet. It is specific to the Bitcoin Core wallet, you won't be able to open it using Electrum.

Comment: Thank you very much for answering my question