# Can Electrum only import private keys of P2PKH addresses?

Tags: address, electrum, private-key-import, import, importaddress

Can Electrum only import private keys of [P2PKH addresses](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Transaction#Pay-to-PubkeyHash) (e.g., "[**1**](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/List_of_address_prefixes)7VZNX1SN5NtKa8UQFxwQbFeFc3iqRYhem")?

Whenever I import private keys of [P2SH addresses](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Pay_to_script_hash) ("[**3**](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/List_of_address_prefixes)EktnHQD7RiAE6uzMj2ZifT9YgRrkSgzQX") or [Bech32 addresses](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Bech32) ("[**bc1**](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/List_of_address_prefixes)qw508d6qejxtdg4y5r3zarvary0c5xw7kv8f3t4"), Electrum doesn't register their funds.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To import private keys of [P2SH addresses](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Pay_to_script_hash) ("[**3**](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/List_of_address_prefixes)EktnHQD7RiAE6uzMj2ZifT9YgRrkSgzQX") or [Bech32 addresses](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Bech32) ("[**bc1**](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/List_of_address_prefixes)qw508d6qejxtdg4y5r3zarvary0c5xw7kv8f3t4") into Electrum, prefix them with "p2wpkh-p2sh:…" or "p2wpkh:…", respectively.