# How do the most popular Bitcoin wallets handle transactions stuck in the mempool with too low fees?

Tags: wallet, transaction-fees, mempool

If unconfirmed for a specific period of time, do popular wallets remove transactions from the mempool? Are there some wallets where if your transaction is never confirmed, your funds are never returned?

Comment: Could you please specify which wallets you consider popular and would like to hear more about?

Comment: Sure. I don't have stats to hand but these are the mobile wallets listed on https://bitcoin.org/en/choose-your-wallet. How do their policies compare?

Comment: Well, that's progress already. ;) So you're trying to figure out which mobile wallet you want to use? What operating system?

Comment: No I already use a number (GreenAddress, Airbitz, Bitwallet etc) I'm interested from a UX perspective.

Comment: I see. Perhaps this related question is of some use: [What happens if your transaction is never confirmed?](http://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/21901/5406)— In regard to your question, perhaps it would work better as "What methods can a thin client offer to resolve stuck transactions?", or you could limited the question to a specific wallet, to make it clear what would constitute a complete answer. Or maybe it'll just work fine. ;)

Answer (score 1):

In general TX is removed after arbitrary time period (14 days for Bitcoin Core) or when mempool size is exceeded and space is needed for fresh TXs. For Bitcoin Core check [this answer](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/a/46162/54847).

Comment: This answer is a bit short and only covers part of the topic. Could you perhaps elaborate?