# My unconfirmed BTC transaction on blockchain just disappeared

Tags: transactions, blockchain, wallet, currencies, mempool

I had an unconfirmed BTC transaction on blockchain.com for about 2 days plus and now I log in and there's no transaction again. I checked blockchain.info using the hash; all wiped nothing is showing, my BTC is gone. Please what should I do? Blockchain support aren't responding either.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What happens if your transaction is never confirmed?](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/21901/what-happens-if-your-transaction-is-never-confirmed)

Comment: Did you send the transaction or were you a recipient?