# Seed for bitcoin-core qt

Tags: bitcoin-core, wallet, encryption

I have a bitcoin core -qt Wallet (on linux). Tell me, can I encrypt it?
 For example, there is the electrum wallet!
It has words for deciphering.
For example, i installed the electrum and the  phrase was generated.
"I'm a fan of the  https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com"
Knowing this phrase you can install electrum on any computer,  and when you enter this phrase you get access to your balance and btc.
But what about bitcoin-core-qt? because it is characterized by the fact that the it must download all the transaction history after installing.(~200gb).
Is there such a "magic phrase:" for this wallet bitcoin-qt?
This is a very useful option if you have lost access to the server or host where you hadthis wallet

Answer (score 1):

You can export private keys from Electrum and BitcoinCore. You can export private keys from Electrum as "words" format (There's a website to convert it to private key(s): https://iancoleman.github.io/bip39/), while Core doesn't have this feature. See the steps in question [Using dumpprivkey to make a paper backup](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/5614/38618) to use `dumpprivkey` in Core to export the private key.

Comment: Thank you, so if i then install Core on new PC and import this privat keys, will i get access to my btc , right or not?

Comment: @D.Joe that is correct. There is more information on that question [here](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/a/71538/75001).

Comment: @MCCCS You should not enter your seed on any website. It is not safe. Besides Electrum does not use bip39 so that site will not work with an Electrum seed. If you want to migrate to a different wallet just send your bitcoins to it using Electrum. If you absolutely must mess about with private keys it is best to use Electrum itself to export them. You can do that via wallet menu > private keys > export.

Answer (score 1):

Bitcoin core does not support seed mnemonics. You must rely on soft copy backups if you want to backup your wallet. The option to backup the wallet file is in the file menu.

If your Bitcoin QT says HD in the bottom right corner then a one time backup is sufficient to get access to your bitcoins at any time in the future. If you care about meta data like address labels you will have to make regular backups.

If it does not say HD then that means you need to make regular backups i.e. at least once every 90 spending transactions.

Answer (score 1):

You can make dump privat keys of all your addresses:
dumpwallet    version 0.13.0 Exports all wallet private keys to file

And other interesting commands:
encryptwallet       Encrypts the wallet with .
importprivkey    [label] [rescan=true]  Adds a private key (as returned by dumpprivkey) to your wallet. This may take a while, as a rescan is done, looking for existing transactions. Optional [rescan] parameter added in 0.8.0. Note: There's no need to import public key, as in ECDSA (unlike RSA) this can be computed from private key.
dumpprivkey     Reveals the private key corresponding to