# Which address do I use to dump private keys from Bitcoin Core wallet?

Tags: bitcoin-core, address, private-key-export

Trying to get my private keys from bitcoin core wallet
Have got to the part where i put in  dumpprivkey then it wants my address
Which address do i give?

Answer (score 1):

It will be the public address that you want the private key for.

The details available in the question here might be useful:
[Using dumpprivkey to make a paper backup](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/5614/using-dumpprivkey-to-make-a-paper-backup)