# why did blockchain.info misstate the value of this transaction

Tags: confirmations

Here is a transaction to SatoshiDice for 0.01 BTC:

[image]

But examine the corresponding entry in blockchain.info:

[image]

They think this:

```
Total Input 0.01974 BTC 
Total Output 0.01973 BTC
```

But that is *innacurate*!

it's acually:

```
Total Input 0.011 BTC 
Total Output 0.010 BTC
```

Why can't they (blockchain.info) see that while SatoshiDice can?

Is it because the transaction is at this point still *unconfirmed*?

Comment: Please add the transaction ID to your question so people can take a look at it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The input and output totals claimed by blockchain.info are **correct**.  But the BTC 0.00973 output is presumably going back to another address owned by your wallet, as [change](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/9007/why-are-there-two-transaction-outputs-when-sending-to-one-address).  Blockchain.info has no way of knowing which output is the "real" destination and which is the change, so it reports the total of both.

SatoshiDice knows which of the two outputs was sent to it (because it controls that address and not the other one).  So they only report the amount that actually went to them.

This has nothing to do with whether or not the transaction is confirmed.

Comment: but neither of those ammounts is what the sender has specified :/

Comment: The sender specified 0.01 to be sent.  Their wallet had a previous transaction output that was for 0.01974, so the wallet software chose to use that transaction as the input.  With a fee of 0.00001, that left 0.00973 to be sent back as change.  The sender's wallet handles this transparently and just shows the net expenditure of 0.01 plus 0.00001 fee.  I suggest a careful reading of the linked question on change.