# bitcoin listunspent showing an address which does not belong to my wallet

Tags: listunspent

I use bitcoin listunspent to list unspent UTXO, but found one that doesn't match my addresses, so what's that address and where is it from ?

```
bitcoin-cli listunspent
[
  {
    "txid": "edc69b3fb53bd221129c4e0f115bdaa5227d01173a23aac2064fc29a78006714",
    "vout": 1,
    "address": "2MtkQ9MeXv9vKeFLuTPeEPfj5DQfWnL1jbw",
    "redeemScript": "0014e329000822d1b101d7940800ff2983aa54b33374",
    "scriptPubKey": "a914107caab5b5a035de348d22aa865d20db3fb1907987",
    "amount": 0.54856181,
    "confirmations": 92,
    "spendable": true,
    "solvable": true,
    "safe": true
  }
]
```

Comment: It is a P2SH, so it's likely a segwit or multisig address. Does `dumpprivkey 2MtkQ9MeXv9vKeFLuTPeEPfj5DQfWnL1jbw` give you a private key?

Answer (score 2):

If you have sent and received Bitcoin before, then this output is likely a [change output](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/9007/why-are-there-two-transaction-outputs-when-sending-to-one-address).