# How do I perform a RBF transaction through Bitcoin Core?

Tags: bitcoin-core, change, replace-by-fee

I have no knowledge about Bitcoin Core and attempted my first transaction, which failed due to low fee due to a basic math error. (Did not notice it was per kilobyte rather than per byte.)
It is currently stuck on chain, in its unconfirmed position.
I see that I likely had the "Replace-by-fee" option enabled.

How does one trigger an RBF?
I have attempted searching around but could not find a definite "guide" on how to perform this in Bitcoin Core. To my understanding I simply send a new transaction with a higher fee to the same recipient and it should replace the old one?

Also, when sending this small transaction (~36k sat), I viewed the txid on explorer and saw that my entire balance was sent, with the remaining BTC being sent to a different address.
What is the function behind this?

Hopefully someone could explain this to me in a newbie friendly manner?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you're using the GUI, head over to the "Transactions" tab, right-click the pending transaction and choose "Increase transaction fee". If you're using bitcoin-cli, use the `bumpfee` command.

The second address you're observing is your change address. See for example [this](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/9007/121614) or [this](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/736/121614) question for an explanation.

Comment: Thanks! This answered everything.
I'm curious if the bumped fee that the GUI suggests is changeable?
Increased the fee from 200 to around 3800 sats. I assume this is based on the suggested fee, but what if I would like to increase it higher than this, without increasing in steps?

Comment: I don't see an option to specify the fee rate in the GUI, but you can use the console (or bitcoin-cli) for that. For example, to increase fee rate to 15 sat/vB, you would use `bumpfee "your txid here" '{"fee_rate":15}'`.