# Will I get my bitcoins have I been scammed?

Tags: synchronization, change

Okay, I'm wondering what's going on here. I recently synced my wallet after ordering some bitcoins, but I never received them. The guy who sent them to me, sent me the blockchain address. So, I don't think he scammed me, but here is the thing:

Looking at [the transaction](https://blockchain.info/tx/ffb1eab51b0eafac05145fc6b47852022538471236d97b955ec84aa15d2a1ac7), on the sending side (the left) is his address and on the receiving side (the right) is mine, but also his address again under which it says "spent". Does that mean he has spent the coins before I received them and I won't get them? Or does it mean, they should be with me and my client is faulty? I was not sure, so I have de-installed the client and reinstalled it, then imported the backup file. I guess, I will soon know, whether it was a fault of my bitcoin client or another issue. However, it said it was connected before, but I never received the bitcoins, so I don't know. What do you think could have happened?

Comment: Can you please proofread your post for spelling and punctuation?  It's very hard to read as it is.

Comment: Ok thanks for that, I am using bitcoin qt 0.8.5 but I was using an earlier version and im still waiting for it to sync as I completely reinstalled it. It wasnt recieving the transaction at all. The problems I had with the old client were it seemed to recieve the blocks, but did not recieve anything uncomfirmed or otherwise when it had finished and also the connection bar in the bottom right was a yellow orange colour, and never turned green or went above 8 connections. I have tried turning firewall off and many other things but to no avail so I deleted the old blockchains and used my wallet ba

Comment: This should really be a comment on @NateEldredge 's post as it is not an answer to the question, but hey, everyone make mistakes here in the beginning :)

Comment: Hi its the same guy who asked the question I would of posted it on @NateEldredge 's post but for some reason when I clicked leave comment it just took me to the top of the page and nothing else happened anyway thanks I apreciate the help.

Comment: You seem to have created another account. You can always comment on your own questions, but to comment on other's questions you need 50 Reputation. See [about] for more information.

Answer (score 3):

The transaction shows that BTC 0.1144 were sent to address 1FCR..., and are still there.  If this was the amount of coins you agreed on, and the address you provided the seller, then he has fulfilled his end of the bargain.  The other output of that transaction, sending BTC 0.2507 back to 1HxK... (from where they were later spent), represents [change](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/736/how-does-change-work-in-a-bitcoin-transaction) and is a normal part of almost every Bitcoin transaction.

If those coins are not showing up in your client, that is a separate problem at your end.  What client are you using?  Does it show the 1FCR... address as an address belonging to you?  Are you sure that it has synced with the block chain?

Answer (score 0):

No worries mate, once the blockchain syncs, you'll see the transaction. Remember, it was 24 weeks ago, so probably a couple days till the 24 weeks sync up and then you'll see yours.