# 2 mBTC that was outputted as change in a transaction I just sent didn't come back to my wallet

Tags: change

Hi I'm new to this so may be asking a stupid question.

I just sent a payment for 198.52 mBTC. There were two outputs. One for 196.39 mBTC that arrived. There was another output of 2 mBTC that didn't arrive and wasn't refunded to the first wallet. I looked on google and I read that the 2 mBTC was change for the transaction. Can somebody tell me how I retrieve this 2 mBTC as it's not in my wallet?

Many thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How does change work in a bitcoin transaction?](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/736/how-does-change-work-in-a-bitcoin-transaction)

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to retrieve it.

Your own wallet created that output, and sent it back to a different address under its own control. Your wallet's balance should reflect this change.

Comment: Thanks for getting back to me. The issue is that my wallets balance does not reflect this change. The recipient has 196.39 mBTC and I have a balance of zero. the 2 mBTC has disappeared.

Comment: Also I just checked my addresses (receiving and change) and the address the change was outputted to isn't in the list.

Comment: What wallet software?

Comment: I am using Electrum on my Mac.