# what is the meaning of Segwit receiving address and segwit change address ..?

Tags: bitcoin-core, bitgo

What is the meaning of different type used in bitgo api like bellow :

Url : https://bitgo.github.io/bitgo-docs/?javascript#add-wallet

> m/0/0/0/0 (which is also the ID used to refer to a wallet in BitGo’s system)
>
> m/0/0/1/0 (The first change address of a wallet)
>
> m/0/0/10/0 (first SegWit receiving address of a wallet)
>
> m/0/0/11/0 (the first SegWit change address of a wallet)

what is the meaning SegWit receiving address or SegWit change address..?

Answer (score 1):

A segwit receiving address is an address that specifies that a segwit output should be created. Many wallet software developers have begun using a different key type and BIP 32 derivation paths for keys that are to be used in segwit addresses. Segwit addresses begin with `bc1` (for native segwit outputs). Segwit change addresses are the same as receiving addresses except are used for your change outputs. These are not typically shown to the user and are managed internally by the wallet.

Comment: What is the role of change address.?

Comment: A change address is where the change in your transaction is sent. See this Q&A: https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/736/how-does-change-work-in-a-bitcoin-transaction

Comment: I would like to add that our Segwit receive addresses are all P2SH-P2WSH, as native bech32 addresses are not yet supported.