# Just received a payment twice from coinbase

Tags: transactions, coinbase.com, coinbase-transaction, withdrawal

Edit: Looks like the error was with my wallet. When I contacted support, they said to have the wallet rescan the block chain. After doing that, my balance went back to 0.

I'm new to bitcoin, but something happened recently that confused me.

It seems one of two things has happened:

A. I received the same payment twice from coinbase.
B. I managed to completely forget a payment made into my wallet from another source.

Possibility A seems very unlikely... but I did receive a payment in my wallet on the 16th that BlockCypher says occurred on the 11th. (I can show the screenshot if anyone cares.)

Here is the rundown of all the transactions (in order) I know of.

I bought 0.02 bitcoin at coinbase.

On Nov 11 I sent 0.01 bitcoins to my desktop wallet. Transaction [here](https://live.blockcypher.com/btc/tx/957dc5976852fdec7880a0544280f431dc3ce33fb31b5f8ff24e1d713b7d58d9/).

On Nov 18 at 13:05 I sent most of that 0.01 to nice hash. Transaction [here](https://blockchain.info/tx/44eef3458e28f135ea5bc771007893ace4b755afd5dffe6ab56e8cb9826599b9). (This seems strange to me now... I sent 0.00948.... I would have thought I would have just sent the full 0.01 I got from coinbase.)

Then I decided I would send some more to nice hash, so I withdrew the rest from my coinbase account. Transaction [here](https://live.blockcypher.com/btc/tx/44eef3458e28f135ea5bc771007893ace4b755afd5dffe6ab56e8cb9826599b9/).

After receiving it in my wallet, I sent everything in my wallet to nicehash. Transaction [here](https://live.blockcypher.com/btc/tx/d4d192382be99b3a03549c4c3c5e5623933d0b021238ea901e27c6b12dce3fed/). The version of the transaction at nicehash (receiving) is [here](https://blockchain.info/en/tx/d4d192382be99b3a03549c4c3c5e5623933d0b021238ea901e27c6b12dce3fed).

So at this point I had (minus miner fees and such) sent 0.02 btc from coinbase to my wallet and then from my wallet to nice hash.

Then, right after I sent this money to Nice Hash, I see a receiving transaction in my wallet, but it is the original transaction from Coin base... the money I thought I had already sent to nice hash 6 days earlier.

So (as far as I can recall), I only paid for 0.02 bitcoin, and yet I have 0.01 bitcoin in my wallet and I have deposits into Nice Hash for 0.02.

I'm hoping someone who knows how to read the blockchain can indicate where the extra 0.01 came from. Unfortunately, my wallet only shows the two transactions from the 18th.

Comment: Can you reference specific Transaction IDs or Addresses so we can verify what you're describing?

Comment: The first one is [change](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/736/how-does-change-work-in-a-bitcoin-transaction) and is completely normal.  Note that the miner fee will *not* appear as an output in the transaction; rather, the fee corresponds to the difference between total inputs and outputs.

Comment: @abelenky, I'm adding transaction ID and address. Note that I have hyperlinked to the blockcypher page for this transaction in the first list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I see in the transaction record is a bit different from what you describe.

I see that account [1FT4bog...](https://blockchain.info/address/1FT4bogBk7c5dqEqroUupSRnSLL4iCPgpm) received 0.01 on November 12th.
That same account spent virtually all of that (0.009292) on November 19th.

I do not see the duplicate transaction you describe.
I do not see that your account received 0.02 or even 0.03.

Comment: Unfortunately, my wallet does not show all my incoming transactions (or else I just do not know how to see them. If I could figure out how to show all my incoming transactions, that would help a lot I'm sure.) _but_ maybe it would help if I showed all the transactions from coinbase and the transactions _into_ the nicehash wallet.  I'll update the original post.

Comment: I have added all the transactions I know of.