# Upon sending remaining wallet contents emptied?

Tags: theft

Three addresses involved in this TX.

1. Address A: My Wallet Address
2. Address B: Recipients Wallet (Coinbase) Address
3. Address C: Unknown!

These are not the exact numbers but the transaction went like so. Wallet A (encrypted) containing 2.0 BTC. Intending to send 0.5 BTC to B. Enter details into client and accept default fee(to be taken from 0.5 BTC). Enter passkey and confirm send. It has now been confirmed 6x.

But now looking at blockexplorer and blockcypher the remaining 1.5 have disappeared to C that is not known to me. TX created had two outputs not one as intended. As far as I can tell I have been done. Is there any other explanation? Intended spend has 6 confs, the other has 5 confs.

*Client: Core 11.2.0*

Comment: This is answered in https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/736/how-does-change-work-in-a-bitcoin-transaction, but in short: it's your own change address. Also, please stop using Bitcoin Core 0.11.2, it's been unmaintained for almost 2 years: https://bitcoincore.org/en/lifecycle/

Comment: Perfect. Didnt know the terminology to search for thus the dupe. RE Client - Its been offline for those two years, and update was on my todo. Thanks Pieter and now be still my beating heart.