# Double transaction on same hash (transaction ID) - Loosing 0.01 btc each time

Tags: transactions, bitcoin-core, blockchain, wallet, transaction-fees

Each time I send some btc to another bitcoin wallet there is a second transaction on the same transaction ID (hash) and each times i am loosing around 75 USD.

You can see by yourself here;

https://www.blockchain.com/btc/address/1NrZWuS4J8MAqX63NHFuLrdmBYf6FttX29

Another weird fact is that on my bitcoin wallet software balance, it's not showing to balance I lost.

Any help would be very appreciated,

Thanks.

Comment: what wallet software are you using? And you mean .001 BTC? The only one that I could see was this one: 5f48a419f861ca157e938492a5a8550a85c4d93749cd7d2bcdb9822be6ee9b3b

Comment: Bitcoin Core Wallet from https://bitcoin.org/en/download

No, I really mean 0.01 BTC

https://www.blockchain.com/btc/tx/5f48a419f861ca157e938492a5a8550a85c4d93749cd7d2bcdb9822be6ee9b3b

https://www.blockchain.com/btc/tx/9d9659dc3633588757798eaf17b8fd19051619561b376384e528271a66df6633

https://www.blockchain.com/btc/tx/50595313b33a2ea0b0a1c2fba5f71a73d72414060d161563d659163930c0145d

Comment: Yeah it looks like change, and it's not .01BTC every time.

Comment: Please have a look on those transactions, you can clearly see 2 different wallets with 2 different transaction on the same transaction ID (hash)

https://www.blockchain.com/btc/tx/5f48a419f861ca157e938492a5a8550a85c4d93749cd7d2bcdb9822be6ee9b3b

https://www.blockchain.com/btc/tx/9d9659dc3633588757798eaf17b8fd19051619561b376384e528271a66df6633

https://www.blockchain.com/btc/tx/50595313b33a2ea0b0a1c2fba5f71a73d72414060d161563d659163930c0145d

Comment: @JohnSmith to clarify: you are confusing terms slightly, a 'wallet' is software that holds a collection of keys, and those keys let you spend bitcoins at addresses related to them. I believe what you are calling a 'transaction ID (hash)' is actually just a bitcoin address. Looking at the 3 txs you linked, I see three UTXOs from the same bitcoin address (`1NrZW...`) being spent to various addresses, with what appears to be a change address generated for each transaction. See the other replies for info on what a change address is. That should answer your main question.

Answer (score 1):

See above link about [How change works](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/736/how-does-change-work-in-a-bitcoin-transaction). Looking at this transaction [5f48a419f861ca157e938492a5a8550a85c4d93749cd7d2bcdb9822be6ee9b3b](https://www.blockchain.com/btc/tx/5f48a419f861ca157e938492a5a8550a85c4d93749cd7d2bcdb9822be6ee9b3b):

(Assuming) you tried to send `.001 BTC` to `1PqarrL2NAobkNbExtjBA1KEzXk7rwPfGQ`, but there did not exist any unspent transaction outputs (UTXO) to satisfy that exact amount (plus tx fee). So your wallet chose to use the UTXO worth `0.01105895 BTC`. It then sent the change (minus tx fee) back to your wallet in a separate output to `147FWjxpW9nYo5Z32qaHSoUZbVCNgsPGuL`. The address for the change is different because it is based on a different public key (it is a [hash of a public key](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Transaction#Pay-to-PubkeyHash), thus a different address), but is presumably still spendable by your wallet.

Comment: allright ! good to know, that's why my wallet software doesn't show the "lost" funds since there is NO lost funds. Thanks a lot for this explanation and I feel way better knowing that I haven't lost some digital gold hehe.