# Bitcoin was sent out and still hasn't been received

Tags: transactions, segregated-witness

I sent bitcoin out to a segwit address (P2SH) and it split the transactions in 2 but I still haven't seen them delivered in into the wallet

Comment: How long ago did you send the Bitcoin? What exactly is the "it" in " it split the transactions in 2"?

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/736/5406