# CoinMe Issue Clarification of Transaction?

Tags: transactions

I made a withdrawal from a CoinMe wallet online to the BTC address 379h4LPA9fGBw6p2zEKnNhCSfayzETdtka for 500.00 however the remainder from that wallet was transferred to this wallet address 1ZX2pmcSNfnpchnBFktZmSy9inDkjnpAW 1824.51. Coinme is now saying , after locking my account, immediately after 500.00 transaction that I have no balance as it was transferred out. How could that happen ? How could my 500.00 withdrawal to one address then split make two payments. Their screens do not offer that as an option. the 500.00 landed safe and sound. why did it take the rest and send to 1ZX2pmcSNfnpchnBFktZmSy9inDkjnpAW . I have attempted to research on my own but cannot understand. I don't understand what to do.  Coinme is insisting that I transferred the entire amount to two serperate wallets.  My hunch is that remainder of my funds were simply moved to another coinme account and my "delightful customer service rep understands even less than I do.  5 Days before XMAS with a 10 year old. Originally they put a "check" in the mail. LOL I need to know what happeened and why. Is there anyone that can explain this to me..  Please

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How does change work in a bitcoin transaction?](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/736/how-does-change-work-in-a-bitcoin-transaction)

Comment: *"My hunch is that remainder of my funds were simply moved to another coinme account and my "delightful customer service rep understands even less than I do."* -- Yes, it sounds like this is normal and expected behaviour, involving a change address (see the link above).