# Please help out I send 109k to my client he was able to receive $50,000 please help

Tags: transactions, address, unconfirmed-transactions, output, output-script-descriptors

I send a bitcoin transaction of all coin my wallet which is $109,180 to my client wallet address giving to me. But he received $50,000 in is wallet address. And I sent all the coin my of 109180. Please what going on and the transaction output is show two wallet, I don’t understand the second wallet that showing I sent the remaining coin there?? Please advice

Comment: Possibly related: https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/736/5406

Answer (score 2):

When transacting Bitcoin, especially large amounts, you should verify the amount in Bitcoin terms. So if it was worth 2.25 Bitcoin at the time, verify that with him. That you agree on the amount in terms of bitcoin.

You can see the transaction hash or transaction ID in your wallet interface to see how much was sent and where it went to. You can also check his wallet address and see his balance.