# Where to look for the lost BTC

Tags: testnet, utxo, lost-bitcoins, lost-transactions

My Tx on btc-testnet seems not transact all the BTC, but there's no UTXO back to my address.
How to find the rest of the BTC?

**Tx** 
7e0cc1e5c944355e6d448de19a67421eef2a6b4ca4ed58fcd990ce75f66d07a9

**1 Input Consumed** 
0.001 BTC from 
mqrNP3qtb6zrphFAkwi9caY8f8v65VbZXx (output)

**1 Output Created** 
0.000007 BTC to 
zJEMNc1JksFTjvvWH2cy97khBgbz5rNYj4 (spent)

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/736/5406

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The difference between total of inputs and total of outputs is the transaction fee that can be claimed by the miner.

It looks as though the software that created the transaction omitted the change output.

---

Related

- [How are fees specified in a TX?](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/112693/13866)

Comment: In another Tx: 3fc1def4614c767bd64f0b202b0842f4701035eb3c6c97185cc54fdbec235c55
I also made the same amount of transaction, but miners charge more. Where can I find the relationship between fee and transaction amount?

Comment: There is no relationship between fee and transaction amount. You offer the fee you think will get the transaction included in whatever time suits you.