# Paper Wallet: can I use the import option in my case?

Tags: transaction-fees, electrum, import, sweep

I have created a paper wallet and I generated the public/private keys with Ubuntu live + Electrum. Now I have 2 questions:

- In this case, can I IMPORT ( instead of SWEEP ) my keys in electrum and avoid to pay the fee each time I want to send my Bitcoin?
- I have read that if you use the IMPORT option, then when you spend a portion of the Bitcoin, then the unspent amount will go to another address. Is it true? Why? Then I have to store another pair keys for the new address?

Thanks, I am newbie ❤️

Answer (score 1):

You can import keys into Electrum. Imported keys cannot be recovered using a recovery / seed phrase, so special care is needed to avoid loss.

Sweeping transfers money into an address corresponding to a key that is generated from the seed of a wallet. So control over that money can be recovered using a recovery / seed phrase. The transfer takes place as a transaction on the Bitcoin Blockchain and so needs to pay a transaction fee. The transaction fee is effectively a bid for space in an auction of space inside blocks.

Comment: and is it true that when I send a portion of my bitcoins the unspent bitcoins will be sent to another address? then how do I access this address? 
Thanks :)

Comment: 1. [How does change work in a bitcoin transaction?](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/736/13866)
2. [Sending certain amount of bitcoin from an address](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/113076/13866)
3. [What does change address mean inside Electrum wallet?](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/50050/13866) -- your wallet takes care of all this for you, you don't have to manage this detail yourself (unless you want to for some reason)