# Transfer amount does not match

Tags: bitcoin-core, transactions

Transfer amount does not match. Sent 0.33, and displayed on blockchain.com - 0.44. Why?
And sent from one address, but the second with a sum of $354 is also displayed. the same thing was transferred to one address with receipt, but the second appeared with the amount of $349. Can I cancel the transaction?
Second address of departure - receipt (for the amount of
$350) could be a hack?
db3129a632971c183264891296e4550e1aa6ca8b527ed60caf11d33ac1676d37

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/736/5406

Answer (score 2):

> **Sent 0.33, and displayed on blockchain.com - 0.44. Why?**

When you give a baker a $50 banknote  for a $33 cake , you get $11 back in change. The delivery person gets a fee of $6.

The value of cake + change is $44.

Your total expenditure is cake + fee = $39 = banknote - change.

---

Your Bitcoin transaction spent a total of 0.04437366 BTC (excluding transaction fees) as follows

| Destination | Amount |
| --- | --- |
| To intended recipient | 0.03200000 BTC |
| Change returned to sender | 0.01237366 BTC |
| Transaction fees to miner | 0.00108465 BTC |

> **Second address of departure /...**

That is change being returned to you.

---

> **Can I cancel the transaction?**

Bitcoin transactions can't be cancelled.

If the transaction opted in to RBF and is unconfirmed you can replace it using RBF - but that is not the same as cancelling it. Look up RBF to understand what can be done.

Comment: Thank you. I see. And why is it hanging for so long not confirmed? 19 hours  Comisia is not a small $30.

Comment: It is most likely hanging because fee-rates are unusually high recently due to a high volume of new usage of the Bitcoin blockchain for other purposes. For guidance on current fee rates see https://bitcoiner.live/ and other sources - you need ~ 600 sat/vByte for a quick confirmation but your transaction has a fee rate of only 157 sat/vByte. You can use RBF to boost the fee if you need a quicker confirmation.