# suspicious transaction from a cold wallet to cold wallet

Tags: transactions, wallet, coldstorage

Dears,

Please help me to understand what happened with a bct transaction I made from one cold wallet address to another.
In short:
I transferred the correct amount in the receiving address and when I check the status, it appears another transaction with a similar but smaller amount to a total unknown btc address. This unknown transaction appears on top of my correct transaction. The transaction(s) is pending since one hour and in the explorer it shows that the transaction will be completed in 12 hours.

Can someone please explain what happened?

Best regards,
g

Comment: Hi, when you say “another transaction”, do you mean that your transaction has two outputs or that there are actually two transactions? Which wallet software/hardware did you use?

Comment: i used trezor and sender and trezor as well for receiver. and yes, it apeears two outputs.

Comment: If your transaction has two outputs, very likely you are looking at a recipient and a change output. The change returns the remainder of the funds from the inputs to yourself. You can read more here: https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/736/5406. If that was the issue, please let us know so we can close your topic as a duplicate, otherwise please follow-up with more information how your problem differs. :)

Comment: it seems clear for me now :). However I still don't understand why the validation of the transaction will take more that 12 hours?

Comment: What feerate did you send it at? The next block currently takes 15+ ṩ/vB, the second next block still 12+ ṩ/vB